# A missing attribute when using { render json: }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, render

I have an app that uses devise for login. I have a login form in a web app that authenticates  a user to the database and simply returns the @user hash as a json string.

The goal is to get the users authenticate the user and retrieve their authentication_token for future use in the app to prevent the user from having to continually log in.

The problem is that I can't get authentication_token to be included in the returned json.

My user.rb Model

```
attr_accessible :authentication_token, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,  :bio, :confirmed, :deposit, :email, :fri25, :mon21, :name, :paid, :picture, :sat26, :sun20, :sun27, :thur24, :tue22, :wed23
```

clearly includes the authentication_token symbol.

Then in the session controller I have a custom action called newApi which runs a simple authentication method and responds with the @user hash as json.

```
def newapi
 @user = User.authenticate(params[:email],params[:password])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @user }
 end
```

eend

Yet no matter what I do the authentication token is not included with the json response. Am I missing something obvious? Why is it not included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem myself by using [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/).

Essentially you just remove the `render json: @user` call and use a jbuilder template.

in newapi.json.jbuilder

```
json.(
  @user, 
  :authentication_token, 
  :email, 
  :password, 
  :password_confirmation, 
  :remember_me,
  :bio, 
  :confirmed, 
  :deposit, 
  :email, 
  :fri25, 
  :mon21, 
  :name, 
  :paid, 
  :picture, 
  :sat26, 
  :sun20, 
  :sun27, 
  :thur24, 
  :tue22, 
  :wed23
)
```

Review their docs if you got this route as there are plenty of It does everything I needed and more and is the only way we do api returns now. If you've not used it before go check it out! it make API endpoints amazingly simple.

Nick Knudson's answer is also valid if you want to roll your own setup.

Comment: An where's is the solution?

You'e "answered" your own question (without providing the solution) marked as the correct one, and dind't even voted up the answer that led you to your solution. This is really not the way to use Stackoverflow.

Comment: Updated answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 4):

Devise > 2.x seems to strip out attributes from xml and json responses. This is likely a security feature, but I'm not sure where it got introduced. The list of "protected attributes" is here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb

line 54:

```
BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION = [:encrypted_password, :reset_password_token, :reset_password_sent_at,
    :remember_created_at, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip,
    :last_sign_in_ip, :password_salt, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at,
    :remember_token, :unconfirmed_email, :failed_attempts, :unlock_token, :locked_at, :authentication_token]
```

and the code that initializes it is on line 122-135

The comments say you can provide your own list of blacklisted attributes or append to the existing list by using `:force_except` and `:except`, respectively.

My hacky solution would be this:

```
def newapi
  @user = User.authenticate(params[:email],params[:password])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @user.as_json(:force_except => Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION.delete_if{|x| x == :authentication_token} }
  end
end
```

But I'm thinking there would be a way to override this list somewhere more elegantly like in an initializer. Mine works, but is likely not the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Though this is old, all I did was use with its "methods" option

```
to_json(methods: :arbitrary_method)
```

since all attributes technically become accessible methods on the model. This seemed most hassle free :D

On this page: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Answer (score 1):

My workaround:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # include devise token_authenticatable and others
  devise  :token_authenticatable

  # after devise finds our user (such as when logging in)
  after_find :write_auth_token

  # write our pseudo attribute to the model
  def write_auth_token
    write_attribute(:auth_token, self.authentication_token)
  end

  # make our pseudo attribute attr_accessible
  attr_accessible :auth_token
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@Travis Todd's answer totally does the work, and yes, there might be a more elegant solution. In addition, if you want to building a private or temporary api for db migration or other similar purposes where you need 2 or more of these blacklist attributes, you might want to do something like:

```
def newapi
  @devise_attrs = [:encrypted_password, :remember_created_at, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at] #etc..
  @user = User.authenticate(params[:email],params[:password]).includes(:identity)
  respond_to do |format|
    # I added a few other options and updated ruby syntax so that you can see how can this be customized if in need of specific user attributes or relations.
    format.json { render json: @user.as_json(force_except: Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION.delete_if{|x| @devise_attrs.include?(x)}, include: [:identity]), status: 200 }
  end
end
```

Still waiting for another finger-licking elegant solution for this.